# Encrypt Arraybuffer with cryptojs

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I try to encrypt an ArrayBuffer with AES so convert is to an wordArray and then to a string:

```
private encrypt(file: ArrayBuffer, key: string): string {
    const wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(file);
    const str = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(wordArray);
    console.log(str); //6920616d206120737472696e67
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, key).toString();
}
```

Now I want to decrypt back to an ArrayButter, but the printed strings do not even match:

```
private decrypt(file: string, key: string) {
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(file, key);
    console.log(decrypted.toString()); //3639323036313664323036313230373337343732363936653637
}
```

I think I messed up some step but I don't know where.

*Update*: I need to convert the string to utf to generate a wordarray:

```
private decrypt(file: string, key: string) {
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(file, key);
    const str = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    const wordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(str);
}
```

Now I am only one step away from converting it to an ArrayBuffer again

Comment: `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: @JonasW. Converting a wordarray to a string in the HEX format because I need to pass a string to the `encrypt` function

Comment: You're encrypting base64 string so what you'll get after decrypting would also be a base64 string.

Comment: @11thdimension where? I am not using base64 at all

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, you're converting the file to base64 to pass to `AES.encrypt()` now after decrypting using `AES.decrypt()` it should again be a  base64 string, which you'll have to convert to wordarray.

Comment: @11thdimension I convert my ArrayBuffer to a wordArray and my wordArray to a string in HEX. at no time I use a base64 string.

Comment: Sorry, I read that as base64. So you'll get a hex string as output, you'll have to convert it to wordarray.

Comment: @11thdimension was able to convert it, updated my question

Comment: Check this out https://gist.github.com/dudepare/99f4d682c3db90ea86a4331e32f0006a

Answer (score 0):

```
function CryptJsWordArrayToUint8Array(wordArray) {
  const l = wordArray.sigBytes;
  const words = wordArray.words;
  const result = new Uint8Array(l);
  var i = 0 /*dst*/, j = 0 /*src*/;
  while (true) {
    // here i is a multiple of 4
    if (i == l) {
      break;
    }
    var w = words[j++];
    result[i++] = (w & 0xff000000) >>> 24;
    if (i == l) {
      break;
    }
    result[i++] = (w & 0x00ff0000) >>> 16;
    if (i == l) {
      break;
    }
    result[i++] = (w & 0x0000ff00) >>> 8;
    if (i == l) {
      break;
    }
    result[i++] = (w & 0x000000ff);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).